# Order of applying css

Tags: css, html, animation, web

I'm working on CSS and web development,but just face a something which i really don't understand it:

```
.header{
position: absolute; 
width:60%;
top: 20%;
left: 50%;
transform: translateX(-50%);<------ executed after animation
text-align: center;
animation: moveUp 2s;
animation-fill-mode: backwards;
}
@keyframes moveUp{
0%{
    opacity: 0;
    transform:translateY(2rem);
   }
100%{
    opacity: 1;
    transform: translateY(0rem);
    }

}
```

so my problem here is the indicated line doesn't apply on ".header" until the animation gets applied in other word it applies animation first then translate -50% ,is there a priority of execution here or it is different thing?

Comment: show us the code of the animation

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Usually the styles are parsed from top to bottom, however this isn't the issue here.

What is happening in your case is the transform is being applied initially, but then it is being overridden by the animation. Once the animation is over, the element is reverting back to its default style which has the transform.

Essentially, even though the transform is applied at first, you don't see it until the element reverts to it after the end of the animation.

The only solution if you want to have the transform *during* the animation, is to include it in the animation itself.

```
@keyframes moveUp {
    0 % {
        opacity: 0;
        transform: translate(-50%, 2rem);
    }
    100 % {
        opacity: 1;
        transform: translate(-50%, 0);
    }
}
```

**EDIT:** To clarify, the order at which the styles are applied does not matter. Whether the animation or the transform is applied first, the result will be the same.

I think a source of your confusion is that the first transform is a `translateX` while the animation only does `translateY`. In both cases what is changing is the value of the `transform` property of the element. Therefore which axis the translation is on doesn't matter. First you set `transform: translateX(-50%)`, but then once the animation kicks in, transform becomes `translateY(2rem)`. The `translateX` part is removed from the `transform`, unless you include it in the animation like I have shown.

Comment: `Usually the styles are applied from top to bottom` they are *parsed* for top to bottom

Comment: Yes i already did this thank you ,just posted the question because wanted to know how and why exactly is behaving this way.

Comment: I guess i understood it if im not wrong ,first when applying animation ,i did set animation-fill-mode:backward  which will apply style of animation first before element gets displayed to the user ,and since in animation did not set tranfrom:translateX so it considered it from the first original place

Comment: @Alexander Check out the edit. I think it will clear some things up